# Can you teach scalpel to recognize a file

Tags: data-recovery

I have a few drives that have been reformatted that I need to retrieve data from. A friend told me that an app like scalpel might be a good option for doing this. After some research it looks like a great tool if you need to recover common file types, but the problem is that I am looking to recover some obscure file types.

The drive has a few RPGMaker2003 projects on it which I highly doubt use common file types and wont be recognized. I have a test project that I just created and I was wondering if it was possible point scalpel (or any other tool for that matter) at this project and teach it what to look for?

Comment: I don't know about scalpel, but I think photorec supports [adding custom file types](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec). Also, many (if not most) obscure file formats are actually based on very common formats, e.g. XML, Tar, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you teach scalpel to recognize a file

Yes, you can define file types in the config file.

For example like [this](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel/blob/master/scalpel.conf) configuration file from TSK's github.